# How to perform grouping in spark scala when key is not same

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, grouping

I want to calculate the total sum of the amounts corresponding to the secondary accounts and compare its value with the primary account. In the following example, the account number that begins with "643" is the primary account and the accounts which appear after that are its secondary. Again another primary account appears which begins with "643" followed by its secondary accounts. I want to group the records that comprises primary and its secondary and compute the sum of the amounts for secondary accounts.

Input:
Account, Amount
643100,  10000  ---- primary account
234100,   4000  ---- secondary account
231300,   1000  ---- secondary account
136400,   5000  ---- secondary account
643841,   20000 ---- next group
562100,   10000
432176,   10000
643304,   40000 ---- next group
124562,   20000
234567,   5000

Output:
Account, Amount, sumofsecamounts
643100,  10000,   10000
643841,  20000,   20000
643304,  40000,   25000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems you need to solve.

1. You aren't guaranteed order on insert. I faced this issue trying to mimic your problem and had to add a column to ensure my data looked like yours.

   1. If your table really does have this order already you are likely ok.
2. You need a column to order data on for a window to work.  Here we will use [monotonically_increasing_id](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id), to help us get that column.
3. You need to partition the data by primary account

   1. You can get around this by using a math trick using 0's for sub accounts so that if you are doing a rolling sum, they don't change the sum and this helps to partition the data.

.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.sql("create table accounts ( Account int, Amount int, order int)") // I had to add order so my data would land in the format you had.
spark.sql("insert into accounts values ( 643100, 10000,1 ), (234100, 4000,2),(231300, 1000,3),(136400, 5000,4),(643841, 20000,5),(562100, 10000,6),(432176, 10000,7),(643304, 40000,8 ),(124562, 20000,9),(234567, 5000,10)")
val increasing = spark.sql("select * from accounts order by order").withColumn("monotonically_increasing_id", monotonically_increasing_id()) // we need a column to order by a column for windows so this give us an ordered field to use. Link to documentation below.
val winowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("monotonically_increasing_id")
increasing
.withColumn("is_Primary", 
  when( col("Account") > 643000, col("Account") )
  .otherwise( 0 ) // This identifies primary & secondary accounts
).withColumn("partition", 
  sum("is_Primary").over(winowSpec)  // rolling sum Trick that partitions data by nature of the fact 0's denote secondary.
).groupBy( 
  col("partition"), //groups primary and secondary
  col("is_Primary") //splits primary vs secondary totals.
).agg( sum("Amount") ).show()
+---------+----------+-----------+
|partition|is_Primary|sum(Amount)|
+---------+----------+-----------+
|   643100|    643100|      10000|
|   643100|         0|      10000|
|  1286941|    643841|      20000|
|  1286941|         0|      20000|
|  1930245|    643304|      40000|
|  1930245|         0|      25000|
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

Once you have this you can easily self join the table if you really want the rows as you described.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id

Comment: Thanks Matt! Appreciate your response.

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried this solution, however Sum ("is_primary" , 1, 0).over(windowSpec) is not working. Can you please help here.

Comment: I'm sorry clearly I had a copy paste error I have fixed the issue.